# Manga involving girl who was raised in the forest and her parents died and she rejoined society and went to a fancy school

Tags: hikari-no-pansy

I remember there was a guy who was with her throughout the manga and became her love interest in the end.

At one point, she got kidnapped and was on an island, where she practiced for a piano recital using a tree root.

At school, she had a super snotty roommate whose father was the Duke and a nice, kind of chubby roommate. At a Halloween party, the snooty roommate dressed up as Cinderella and the chubby girl as an angel. The main protagonist dressed up as a monkey and got made fun of, and the guy showed up to help her out and she changed her costumes into a princess.

In the end, they had kids and they ran around all over the place and everyone lived happily ever after.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the manga your mentioning is called [**Pansy**](http://myanimelist.net/manga/5966/Hikari_no_Pansy).

A girl is raised by monkeys before being brought to where people are and eventually meets the crown prince. It turns out her family was good at pianos.